# BREAKING CHANGE: The request './components/mycomponentx/MyComponentX' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I have a components library that uses `"type":"module"` in `package.json` with `typescript`, I used `babel ./src --config-file ./babel.esm.config.json --out-dir lib/esm --copy-files --extensions .ts,.js,.tsx` to build this component library and published as `PackageX`. Then I am trying to use one component of this library in a another react app that I created using `create-react-app` command. I've ensured to add my `PackageX` to `package.json` in new react app, but when I try to run the react app I get this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/mycomponentx/MyComponentX' in 'D:\Work\test-bootstrapper\my-app-test\node_modules\<package_name>\lib\esm'
Did you mean 'MyComponentX.js'?

BREAKING CHANGE: The request './components/mycomponentx/MyComponentX' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
```

Babel package version:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5"
```

Any idea what additional configuration is required?

Comment: did you solve this problem?@John

Comment: @liangqicai: `babel` was having some issue then, and fix was critical for me so I moved to `webpack`.